# Linker error if .m is imported in header files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Why does importing `.m` files lead to linker errors?

**PS**: if you find this question too small [or abstract] to be answered, please post in comments. I'll try to post few scenarios. But, this is a general behavior that iOS developers would be easily familiar with.

Comment: Where are you importing your .m files, I guess in code files we import .h files. Please elaborate your use case

Comment: Exactly my point - we import `.h` files but what I want to understand is, why we get linker error, if we import `.m` file instead of corresponding `.h`

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038532/objective-c-import-m-and-h-file-what-does-it-do

Comment: Usually Mach-O Linker Error means you have not included a header file for a function you are using in your code. So you must import a `.h` file otherwise you will get a linker error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified overview of the build process. The input of the compiler is something called a "translation unit". A translation unit is a `.m` file, with the contents of all included / imported header files pasted into it. It compiles each translation unit separately into an object file (`.o`). Each object file has a symbol table containing all symbols that are defined in the associated translation unit.  At this stage a symbol is just a name that can be referenced from generated code. It is then the linker's job to associate an address to each symbol, and then replace each reference to the symbol in the generated code by its address, to produce the final executable. In an object file's symbol table you can have symbols that are either defined or undefined. An undefined symbol is a symbol that is referenced in the object file, but not defined inside it. The linker will need to find a suitable definition in another object file later in the process. A defined symbol means that the object file provides the symbol's definition. When the linker encounters such a symbol in an object file's symbol table, it can immediately assign it to an address. If later on it finds another object file with a defined (global) symbol of the same name, it stops with a duplicate symbol error.

Let's take the example of the following `.m` files:

a.m:

```
int my_global;
```

b.m:

```
#include "a.m"

my_global = 3;
```

The compiler sees the two following translation units:

a:

```
int my_global;
```

b:

```
int my global;
my_global = 3;
```

It treats them separately, and emits a.o and b.o that both have the symbol `my_global` as a defined symbol in their symbol table. When the linker encounters the second of the two, it will complain about a duplicate symbol.

To solve the issue you can create a header file called `a.h` containing an external declaration of `my_global`, and include that from `b.m`:

a.h

```
extern int my_global;
```

b.m

```
#include "a.h"

my_global = 3;
```

The b translation unit is now this:

```
extern int my_global;

my_global = 3;
```

Now the symbol will be undefined in b.o, and the linker will resolve it to the symbol defined in a.o.

For more about what linkers do, you can read [this excellent article](https://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html).